# Can "the line" be in a circle?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Source: https://baitap365.com/bai-viet/88963-giai-bai-23-doc-rong-ran-len-may-sgk-tieng-viet-2-tap-1-ket-noi-tri-thuc-voi-cuoc-song#!#google_vignette

A group of children walked one after another in a circle or almost a circle or a complete circle. They just walked like that just like a moving merry-go-round machine. The children were playing.

I said to my daughter, who was standing nearby, "**would you like to join the line?**"

**Can a line not be straight?**

I am not sure if "**would you like to join the circle?**" sound correct?

Comment: From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-a-circle-a-straight-line/:  "The line which is placed at 180 degrees is a straight line. And, when we see a circle, it has uncountable or infinite numbers of sides and internal angles measured as 180 degrees. The interior angle of a circle is also 180 degrees which means equal to a straight line." so by extension, circle is a line, and hence it will be technically, mathematically and otherwise OK to say 'join the line' even if the line is a circle.

Comment: @SanjeevPandey - in British English we distinguish between a drawn or geometric 'line' which may be straight or curved, and a line or queue of people, which can be any shape one likes.

Comment: I'd say "would you like to join the circle?"

Comment: @SanjeevPandey But more importantly, the OP wasn't asking within the context of strict geometry.

Comment: If the children were forming a complete circle it would probably be more natural to call it a circle, as a line normally has a beginning and an end. If it was a nearly complete circle, that could be a line: there's no definite geometry but you normally use the most accurate common word. It would also depend on how they were standing: people in a line commonly face the back of the person in front, while in a circle you would be less likely to stand front-to-back, and might be all holding hands with your arms forming a ring.

Comment: I would call it a circle if I cannot tell which member, if any, is first.

Answer (score 4):

"Line" can mean:

- a geometrical object (typically straight: "the shortest path between two points is a *line*")
- an object drawn on a piece of paper or a screen ("a 2B pencil  makes a very dark *line*")
- a queue (a *line* of people — like here)

and probably more.

So.  You could say (not *talk*) to your daughter who was (not *is*) standing nearby: "Would you like to join the line?" (especially if there is a beginning and end of the line, as in the picture above).  Or you could say "join the circle".  The purpose of the sentence is to let the child know she can play with the others.  This doesn't require a lot of geometrical rigor.  (Nobody would ever say "join the arc")

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is **yes**, a "line" can be curved. [Here's a dictionary entry for "line"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/line). It has many meanings! One of them talks about geometry and says "especially: such an element that is straight." But there are many other usages, from fishing line to telephone lines, and even another geometry usage that says "a straight *or curved* geometric element," or says that it can even mean the same thing as "curve." This is why we often have to specify "a *straight* line."

What all these types of lines have in common is that they're narrow (compared to their context) and they connect (they're "linear"). So yes, a line of people, including a children's game like [Crack the whip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crack_the_whip), can be called a "line."

In practice, there's nothing wrong with "Would you like to join the line," but also nothing wrong with "... join the circle" if the line was forming a circular shape at that moment (*or* sometimes a group of friends can be called a "circle" by metaphor). But even more likely would simply be "Would you like to join the game?"

Answer (score 0):

A standard line in mathematical context is a straight never-ending line.
But in this context, they use the word line as more of a waiting line.
While there are various approaches to this concept, I think that
"Would you like to join the group", or "Would you like to join the circle" would be more accurate here.

Comment: Even within the constraints of mathematics, is a line really necessarily infinite?

Comment: @Joachim Yes, lines do go on forever in both directions without any end. Take the Ruler Postulate, which describes that any point on a line can match with any real number, of which there are infinite. Rays are also infinite, because even if they have one fixed 'end,' they still have an end that stretches on forever. When people think of lines with two ends (and that aren't infinite) they are thinking of line *segments*, which have defined start and end points. This description of a line does adhere to actual geometry, and is real math.